# Project Euler #13 in Python, trying to find smart solution

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve problem 13 from Euler project, and I'm trying to make the solution beautiful (at least, not ugly). Only "ugly thing" I do is that I'm pre-formating the input and keep it in the solution file (due to some technical reasons, and 'cause I want to concentrate on numeric part of problem)
The problem is "Work out the first ten digits of the sum of the following one-hundred 50-digit numbers."
I wrote some code, that should work, as far as I know, but it gives wrong result. I've checked input several times, it seems to be OK...

```
nums=[37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250,
46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538,
74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629,
91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250,
23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676,
89261670696623633820136378418383684178734361726757,
28112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738,
44274228917432520321923589422876796487670272189318,
47451445736001306439091167216856844588711603153276,
70386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951,
62176457141856560629502157223196586755079324193331,
64906352462741904929101432445813822663347944758178,
92575867718337217661963751590579239728245598838407,
58203565325359399008402633568948830189458628227828,
80181199384826282014278194139940567587151170094390,
35398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586,
86515506006295864861532075273371959191420517255829,
71693888707715466499115593487603532921714970056938,
54370070576826684624621495650076471787294438377604,
53282654108756828443191190634694037855217779295145,
36123272525000296071075082563815656710885258350721,
45876576172410976447339110607218265236877223636045,
17423706905851860660448207621209813287860733969412,
81142660418086830619328460811191061556940512689692,
51934325451728388641918047049293215058642563049483,
62467221648435076201727918039944693004732956340691,
15732444386908125794514089057706229429197107928209,
55037687525678773091862540744969844508330393682126,
18336384825330154686196124348767681297534375946515,
80386287592878490201521685554828717201219257766954,
78182833757993103614740356856449095527097864797581,
16726320100436897842553539920931837441497806860984,
48403098129077791799088218795327364475675590848030,
87086987551392711854517078544161852424320693150332,
59959406895756536782107074926966537676326235447210,
69793950679652694742597709739166693763042633987085,
41052684708299085211399427365734116182760315001271,
65378607361501080857009149939512557028198746004375,
35829035317434717326932123578154982629742552737307,
94953759765105305946966067683156574377167401875275,
88902802571733229619176668713819931811048770190271,
25267680276078003013678680992525463401061632866526,
36270218540497705585629946580636237993140746255962,
24074486908231174977792365466257246923322810917141,
91430288197103288597806669760892938638285025333403,
34413065578016127815921815005561868836468420090470,
23053081172816430487623791969842487255036638784583,
11487696932154902810424020138335124462181441773470,
63783299490636259666498587618221225225512486764533,
67720186971698544312419572409913959008952310058822,
95548255300263520781532296796249481641953868218774,
76085327132285723110424803456124867697064507995236,
37774242535411291684276865538926205024910326572967,
23701913275725675285653248258265463092207058596522,
29798860272258331913126375147341994889534765745501,
18495701454879288984856827726077713721403798879715,
38298203783031473527721580348144513491373226651381,
34829543829199918180278916522431027392251122869539,
40957953066405232632538044100059654939159879593635,
29746152185502371307642255121183693803580388584903,
41698116222072977186158236678424689157993532961922,
62467957194401269043877107275048102390895523597457,
23189706772547915061505504953922979530901129967519,
86188088225875314529584099251203829009407770775672,
11306739708304724483816533873502340845647058077308,
82959174767140363198008187129011875491310547126581,
97623331044818386269515456334926366572897563400500,
42846280183517070527831839425882145521227251250327,
55121603546981200581762165212827652751691296897789,
32238195734329339946437501907836945765883352399886,
75506164965184775180738168837861091527357929701337,
62177842752192623401942399639168044983993173312731,
32924185707147349566916674687634660915035914677504,
99518671430235219628894890102423325116913619626622,
73267460800591547471830798392868535206946944540724,
76841822524674417161514036427982273348055556214818,
97142617910342598647204516893989422179826088076852,
87783646182799346313767754307809363333018982642090,
10848802521674670883215120185883543223812876952786,
71329612474782464538636993009049310363619763878039,
62184073572399794223406235393808339651327408011116,
66627891981488087797941876876144230030984490851411,
60661826293682836764744779239180335110989069790714,
85786944089552990653640447425576083659976645795096,
66024396409905389607120198219976047599490197230297,
64913982680032973156037120041377903785566085089252,
16730939319872750275468906903707539413042652315011,
94809377245048795150954100921645863754710598436791,
78639167021187492431995700641917969777599028300699,
15368713711936614952811305876380278410754449733078,
40789923115535562561142322423255033685442488917353,
44889911501440648020369068063960672322193204149535,
41503128880339536053299340368006977710650566631954,
81234880673210146739058568557934581403627822703280,
82616570773948327592232845941706525094512325230608,
22918802058777319719839450180888072429661980811197,
77158542502016545090413245809786882778948721859617,
72107838435069186155435662884062257473692284509516,
20849603980134001723930671666823555245252804609722,
53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690]
result_sum = []
tmp_sum = 0
for j in xrange(50):
    for i in xrange(100):
        tmp_sum += nums[i] % 10
        nums[i] =nums[i] / 10
    result_sum.insert(0,int(tmp_sum % 10))
    tmp_sum = tmp_sum / 10
for i in xrange(10):
    print result_sum[i]
```

Comment: In the project-euler tag you used it says "Please be aware that the purpose of Project Euler is to encourage people to think and learn so publishing the solution or working code would render this process useless." ....

Comment: 1) I know 2) this solution is not working 3) there are lots of solutions to this problem in the internet, one more solution won't spoil the situation

Comment: I've posted another answer; I think you'll like it.

Comment: you could always read the data from a .txt file using the __open()__ statement and remove the "\n" using a strip() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works by adding all the numbers in `nums` like a person would: adding column by column.  **Your code does not work because when you are summing the far left column, you treat it like every other column**.  Whenever people get to the far left, they write down the entire sum.  So this line

```
result_sum.insert(0,int(tmp_sum % 10))
```

doesn't work for the far left column; you need to insert something else into result_sum in that case.  I would post the code, but **1)** I'm sure you don't need it, and **2)** it's agains the Project-Euler tag rules.  If you would like, I can email it to you, but I'm sure that won't be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You could save the numbers in a file (with a number on each line), and read from it:

```
nums = []
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    for num in f:
        nums.append(int(num))

# nums is now populated with all of the numbers, so do your actual algorithm
```

Also, it looks like you want to store the sum as an array of digits.  The cool thing about Python is that it automatically handles large [integers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types).  Here is a quote from the docs:

> Plain integers (also just called integers) are implemented using long in C, which gives them at least 32 bits of precision (sys.maxint is always set to the maximum plain integer value for the current platform, the minimum value is -sys.maxint - 1). Long integers have unlimited precision.

So using an array of digits isn't really necessary if you are working with Python.  In C, it is another story...

Also, regarding your code, you need to factor in the digits in `tmp_sum`, which contains your carry-over digits.  You can add them into `result_sum` like this:

```
while tmp_sum:
    result_sum.insert(0,int(tmp_sum % 10))
    tmp_sum /= 10
```

This will fix your issue.  [Here](http://ideone.com/F3bHUs), it works.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the problem. The problem is that there is a mistake in the code that makes answer wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have all the numbers in a list, you should be able to take the [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) of them pretty easily.  Then you just need to take the first ten digits of the sum.  I won't put any code here, though.

Comment: It seems to me, that it's not very beautifl way to solve this problem. Anyway, I know several ways this problem can be solved. I just  want to understand what's wrong with my solution

Comment: When you say you want an "elegant" solution, do you mean you want an obfuscated one?

Comment: Um, when I first looked at the problem I thought "Okay, they want me to have problems with too big numbers" So I started to think how to avoid this. I assume that this solution takes less memory (though much more time) that the simpliest one. So let's assume I wanted to get memory-optimized solution

Comment: In any case, my current interest is not to get other solution. It's to correct mine, as the best way to learn - is on own mistakes

Answer (score 1):

**As Simple as this :**

Values.txt will contain all digits.

```
nums = []

with open("values.txt",'r') as f:
    for num in f:
        nums.append(int(num))

print(str(sum(nums))[:10])
```

Comment: It would be great if you would read the question first. You might then notice that I wasn't looking for just any working solution, but rather for what's wrong with one provided. And there is an answer to the question already.

Answer (score 0):

Just as easy is storing it in csv and using pandas:

```
def foo():
    import pandas as pd 
    table = pd.read_csv("data.txt", header = None, usecols = [0])
```

and then iterate through panda dataframe:

```
    sum = 0 
    for x in range(len(table)):
        sum += int(table[0][x])

    return str(sum)[:10]
```

just keep in mind that Python handles the large digits for you.

Comment: As you might have noticed in my comments to other questions, I was _not_ looking for a *different* solution, I was looking what was wrong with mine.